# Webpage redirection time

Tags: javascript, navigation, redirect

I want to calculate time consumed in redirecting from 1 webpage to another webpage.
For Example:

1) I am using Facebook in Google Chrome browser.
I have shared 1 link on my Facebook profile like below:

http://www.webdeveloper.com/

(It's not only Facebook. It can be any domain having link to another domain).

2) When I click on this link from my Facebook profile, then this website will open in new tab.

3) I want to calculate time difference in miliseconds or microseconds between below two events:

First Event: Time of clicking link "http://www.webdeveloper.com/" from my Facebook profile.

Second Event: Time of completely loading webpage of "http://www.webdeveloper.com/".

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can't see anything other than a browser plugin being able to do this..

Comment: Can you please recommend me any browser plugin ?

Comment: Cannot readily remember any that does this. But you should be able to roll out your own FF plugin by capturing and recording the url open events.

Comment: Please don't cross post - http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/36146/webpage-redirection-time, http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/38501/webpage-redirection-time, http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/178033/webpage-redirection-time and http://superuser.com/questions/513595/webpage-redirection-time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless you load the linked page yourself into a frame or with xmlhhtp request, your facebook page does not have control of another page. In other words, as soon as the user clicks the link you have no control and it runs separately. If you use a frame or load the page ajax style with javascript into an object, it's not going to give you the same kind of timing. So this is basically a pointless excercise as you can't do it. You could potentially setup your own browser with whatever analyzer so it will give you timings but you can't set up any code that would time it for visitors, for the aforementioned reason. If it was possible to do such things then this code could also manipulate the linked to page and take over it. With such lax security you couldn't trust any link you click.